# How to get React app to load after Netlify redirect?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I have deployed a React app on Netlify by linking it to a github repository. I then took the step of creating a catch all redirect as described by the Netlify docs.

This solved the 'Page not found' issue and was redirecting to index.html (in the /public folder I believe) after which it would just remain a blank page. To add some clarity, I have the '_redirects' file in the /public folder.

I previously trying putting it in the /build folder but that didn't work. I was getting the 'page not found' error.

For reference this is the contents of my '_redirects' file:

```
#Redirects from what the browser requests to what we serve

/*      /index.html     200
```

The app is not loading from the index.html file being served. How do I approach solving this issue?

Comment: Did you put the build command right when it opted for, during the linking process ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: What were the steps you went through while deploying this site?